# AI that merges best photos

Tags: photo-editing, software-recommendation

Let’s say I take a family picture. I take 3 shots. 
Then looking at the results, I see that on each shot a different person is either not looking at the camera or closing his eyes.

I remember reading about technologies that would automagically merge the shots to make the best of all 3.

I can’t figure out where I read it or which software did this, or what to look for exactly ...

Comment: One way is to do it the old fashioned way by hand. GIMP/PS, cut out the good face, put it on top of the bad face, stamp tool on the background (bad face picture) for the edges, stamp tool on neck to make it look seamless, some final touches here and there, voilá

Comment: Yes that’s what we did now, but not being expert, I was hoping recent AI would be better at it...

Comment: There might be something, I mean, theres decent faceswap on snapchat and similar, but a simple "swap" might not always be sufficient, if you want a professional looking picture. (Especially around the edges you might get bad results)

Answer (score -1):

In Photoshop, you can use Photoshop to stack the images.

[image]

If you go to File > Scipts > Load Photos Into Stack

Photoshop will try to stack the images as close as possible.  Then you will assort the images with the best images on the bottom of the layer then the other layers you want the better of the faces ontop.

You will then create a layer mask starting with the mask all in black. Then you use the paintbrush with the white color and paint on the layer mask of the faces you want on the original image.